# How close can we get to duplicate the conditions of big bang?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, big-bang, particle-accelerators

The particle accelerator has attempted to smash gold nucleus together to reproduce the moment of or after big bang, how close can we go and how to verify if that result is not a fluke? Can we create a big bang?

Comment: The big bang is a nebulous concept, GR predictions break down, and so questions like _can we create a big bang_ are in many ways meaningless. They  erroneously imply that the big bang occurred at a point, which has been dealt with many times here. My answer is based around what the experiments found compared to theorised predictions of what the early universe may have "looked" like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of comparing what our accelerators **can** achieve compared to the theorised state of the universe **just after** the big bang, is to see if   we can create for a short time and in a small region,  a mixture of all kinds of particles moving at near light speed.

This mixture of particles should initially exist with a weakly bound quark gluon plasma predominating.

In  heavy-ion collisions within accelerators, a small proportion of protons and neutrons contained within gold and lead  nuclei collide at  energy scales of upwards of a few trillion electronvolts each,  forming a miniscule fireball in which everything “melts” into a quark-gluon plasma.

[image]

**Relativistic Heavy Ion Collisions**

Image Source [Heavy Ion Collisions](http://snelling.web.cern.ch)

As this tiny fireball cools, individual quarks and gluons combine to produce a mixture of entities such as mesons (which are made of a quark and an antiquark), examples of these are  pions and kaons,   and 3 valence quark hadrons,   protons and neutrons being examples of these composite particles, as well as  antiprotons and antineutrons, which may combine to form the nuclei of antiatoms as heavy as helium.

An important early discovery resulting from these heavy ion collisions was that the quark-gluon plasma appears to act  more like a perfect fluid with little viscosity, rather than the expected gas phase.

[image]

**Jet Quenching observed by CMS in heavy-ion collisions.**

Image Source: [CERN CMS Experiment](http://cms.web.cern.ch)

When  pairs of quarks or gluons collide and then scatter at angles based around a reversal of their original direction, a spurt of energy results  that quickly condenses to a jet of pions, kaons, and other particles as can be seen above. Jets are fundamental to quantum chromodynamics, the theory that explains how quarks and gluons can combine depending on their different “colors”.

Answer (score 1):

Particle accelerators reach ~10 TeV energies, roughly the equivalent of particles at $10^{-15}$s after the big bang and prior to the electroweak transition. However,  I think there is a problem in claiming a reproduction of the conditions in the big bang if there is no semblance of thermal equilibrium.

Astrophysically, the conditions in the early universe are regularly reproduced in the cores of massive stars, near and at the ends of their lives.

Temperatures of $10^{11}$K and very high densities are achieved, which is comparable to that of the "lepton era", spanning from about $10^{-3}$ seconds after the big bang to the formation of nucleons at around 1 second.